# What do the stars in the Koren daily siddur mean

Tags: torah-reading

Three of the four Torah readings for chol ha-moed Succos have a star. The Torah readings for other days do not have such stars. What might these stars mean?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or specify which are marked?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the Koren siddur on page 1155 the Torah reading for the First day of Chol Hamoed Succos. The break for each section of the leining has the person who is being called up on the left side of the page. For example לוי is next to the word כבשים which is the eighth word of the pasuk. The actual start of the pasuk וביום השלישי has a tar next to וביום in order to show where the reading actually starts. The other sectionsare similar. Note that רביעי does not has a star because the reading starts at the beginning of the printed line וביום השני

The other readings for Chol Hamoed are similar. If you look at other readings, you will see it is similar. For example, page 1144 eighth day of Pesah, the שלישי on a weekday has the star because the reading starts in the middle of the printed line. The other two above it start at the beginning of the printed line and do not need the star.